# Insert with Select and Limit 1 results in duplicate key error

Tags: mysql, select, insert, duplicates, limit

I have following problem:

```
INSERT INTO track (`TrackId`, `ArtistId`) 
(
   SELECT 300000001, artist.artistId
   FROM artist 
   WHERE NormalizedArtist LIKE 'djotzinikp'
   limit 1
);
```

This results in a duplicate key error but the table actually has no entry with the given id. The Select itself (without the LIMIT) returns 2 rows. Is it not possible to apply a LIMIT here, so i only get one row in the select? I also tried to store it in a temporary select but this did not work, too. Isn´t there a way?

Comment: Yes it [is](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1bb6a/1) possible to apply `LIMIT`.

Comment: I'm sorry.  I believe the database.  You have a duplicate key error . . . you need to check the primary key as well as any unique keys.

Comment: Only the TrackId is a Primary key. We also have 3 indices on Trackname, ArtistId and ReleaseId. But is a index automatically unique? How do i check these unique keys?

Comment: I just found the error, there was a hardcoded string wich loaded a other version of the database, where the entrys where allready made... Still,thanks for the help =)